# How do I automatically update a Subversion working copy?

Tags: windows, svn, scripting

Does anybody know how I can automatically run `svn update`? If anybody has a script or something like that, could you show me an example?

Comment: How do you mean automatic? At what point should the update command be run automatically?

Comment: What operating system will you be using to do the updates (Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc)?

Comment: I would not really recommend using an automatic update. Strange things can happen when you have changes that conflict with somebody else's changes, but your local files are then updated anyway.

Answer (score 109):

I'm using TortoiseSVN. On the production server I have a scheduled task that runs the following batch file.

```
CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\www\MyRepo\" /closeonend:0
```

Hopefully this saves someone else some time!

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Just adding a note to future readers who might want to update multiple directories simultaneously, see my question (and answer) here: http://superuser.com/a/689155/264136

Comment: Well saved me some times, what, 4 years later now? Thanks! :)

Comment: and more +1 4 years later :)

Comment: +1 This is perfect. I just need my production server to update. So as long as the working copy is clean I won't have to worry about conflicts (as I do not develop on the server). Thanks!

Comment: +1, as someone new to managing a windows production server, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 32):

I use [SVN Notifier](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/) which sits in the system tray and notifies me every time the repository changes. And I can highly recommend it. It means you only update when there's something to update!

Alternatively you can set up a scheduled task/cron job to run `svn update` in the appropriate directory every hour/day/whatever.

---

**EDIT:** OK, take a look at [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) on setting up a scheduled task.

You want a batch file called svnUpdate.bat or something which looks like this:

```
cd C:/path/to/your/working/copy
svn update
```

Get the scheduled task to run this as often as you like (once an hour seems sensible)

Make sure you have the command line version of svn installed (I use [SlikSvn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)) and available on your PATH (in a command window type `svn` and ensure it says 'Type svn help...' or similar.

Comment: Batch script will be the best solution

Comment: Could you write full script for update, because I dont know what to run, and don't see anythig like update in may Installed folder.

Comment: The command 'svn update' runs the svn program and tells it to update. These is no separate 'update' program. In a command prompt try typing svn update to check it works

Comment: I use this batch script to update my working copy every 5 seconds, as scheduled tasks and cron can only run scripts every minute `:begin\nsvn update C:\data\localweb\development\ntimeout 5\ngoto begin` where \n is newline

Comment: you could also write (instead of switching directory): `svn update %path%`

Answer (score 16):

```
@echo off

cls
echo == Initiating system instance variables...
echo. -- Setting the variables...

:: Here you need to make some changes to suit your system.
set SOURCE=C:\sauce\CURRENT
set SVN=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin

:: Unless you want to modify the script, this is enough.

echo. %SOURCE%
echo. %SVN%
echo. ++ Done setting variables.
echo.
echo == Updating source from SVN
echo. -- Running update...
"%SVN%\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:update /path:"%SOURCE%" /closeonend:2
echo. ++ Done.

echo. -- Cleaning up...
set SOURCE=
set SVN=
echo. ++ Done.
```

If you are using TortoiseSVN then the above batch script will suit fine. Otherwise you can just modify it to use whatever SVN client you are currently using. Just pop this in a .bat file and run it on demand.

Comment: This is the relevant portion for a much larger "Build, destroy and deploy" script I wrote so there might be some comments or echos that you might prune.

Comment: I should copy this script in repository folder?

Comment: This is good, but I need update changes at my project (not version of SVN).

Comment: You can put this batch file on your desktop. Modify the SOURCE variable (I use C:\sauce\CURRENT) to whatever directory you have your checked out trunk in. The SVN variable I set to the installation directory where TortoiseSVN (an SVN client) can be found. The script then runs the TortoiseSVN executable with a few parameters to tell Tortoise what directory to run an SVN update on. This will update your project with the newest files from the SVN repository. Not the application itself.

Comment: You can easily modify this script to run the update command from whatever SVN client you are currently using.

Answer (score 6):

You can also download and use *Commit-Monitor* from http://code.google.com/p/commitmonitor/. It monitors SVN repositories for commits and notifies the user when it happens. It is in GNU GPL, ver 2.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Once I know your operating system, I will be able to give you a more detailed answer.

**General Instructions**

1. Never change anything in the local repository.
2. Read this [link on how to use AT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313565) to schedule from the command line in windows.
3. Use the AT command to schedule the following command (assuming you have the command-line version of svn installed):

   svn update reporsitory_directory
4. Profit!

Comment: Me should some way to run update by double click on one file.

Comment: Then you could just create a windows shortcut that executes svn update repository_directory

Comment: Look, I don't have .exe file in my repository directory witch run update. I can give you list of all files in my repository folder.