# Is there any tool that can monitor status of my working copies from SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I'm looking for a tool that will alert me (or let me check the status of multiple folders) whenever I have some pending changes in my working copies.
I have multiple projects that I work on and I could really use a tool that would grab my attention in such case.
I know that TortoiseSVN has icon overlays that would do the job if it worked well, but it doesn't.
I tried, and had more issues with TortoiseSVN than before.

I don't want to periodically go through 10+ projects and do TortoiseSVN"s "Check for modifications" manually.
I'm looking for some other solution.

UPDATE:
I might actually be fine with a script.
The key thing is that upon execution I should get a status of multiple working copies.

Comment: What is wrong with Tortoise?  Its the best windows svn client out there?

Comment: You should check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919822/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-subversion-repository

Comment: @Nix: Gosh, I have multiple issues with TortoiseSVN, it's a long list really. I'm about to force myself to command line tools. I've read they're rock solid.

Comment: I have always liked command line tools better, but I have never had issues with Tortoise...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.svnmonitor.com/default.shtml

> What is SVN-Monitor?
>   Perform all your
>   commonly-used svn-actions (update,
>   commit, revert, diff ...)
>   Keep your
>   source up-to-date with minimum
>   conflicts and manual merges
>   Browse and
>   search the svn log from your computer
>   while offline (disconnected from the
>   svn repository)
>    Be constantly aware of
>   your local source modifications,
>   without using any Visual Studio plugin
>   Keep a local updated mirror of the
>   repository, while not affecting your
>   changes, without the need to commit
>   Monitor the source for certain events
>   Receive notifications of any kind
>   (balloon popups, tray icons, email,
>   sounds, ...) when certain events occur

Comment: I know of this one, it's very feature rich, but I don't like the UI of the particular part I need. It's a sidebar rather than the main part of the UI. To do simple monitoring of the remote repo (not my local working copies) I use CommitMonitor which does just what I need, except it doesn't monitor my local working copies for uncommited changes.
Anyway I think I'll give SVN-Monitor a chance :)

Comment: Since your reply is 100% correct, regardless of my personal preferences I'm marking it as an answer.

Comment: do you know what happened to the SVN-Monitor? They changed the start page. Can't find the download link :(

Answer (score 0):

Check out the notifier.

http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/

> SVN Notifier is a simple and useful tool to monitor your Subversion project repository for changes. SVN Notifier notifies you about recent commits and helps you keep your local copy up to date. You can review all the changes and update your local copy right from the application.

Comment: This tool does what I need. Well almost. It does not warn you about new unversioned files, but it still helps a lot (the UI is cleaner and more focused on what I'm looking for). Thanks.