# Can multiple people work on the same project?

Tags: java, eclipse

Can me and my other friend programmer work on same project with Eclipse synchronizing it, or we need to share the src every 10 minutes?

Comment: You need a version-control system such as SVN or (recommended) git. You commit all your files to the system and the system takes care of different edits by different people. It doesn't mean commiting every 10 minutes.

Comment: @AshishAgarwal No, that question is way more specific than this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly use the "Team" menu, which gives you access to version control systems. I would recommend Git or Mercurial (Distributed Version Control Systems).

[EGit/JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) are now part of the mainstream plugins: you can install them using the "Indigo" repository (assuming Eclipse 3.7) in "Install new software...".

Centralised Version Control Systems (like CVS or SVN) also have plugins for Eclipse. They might, however, make it more difficult to branch and merge conflicts when required.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for a version control system (VCS) like CVS, SVN, Git, Mercurial, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are asking if Eclipse has support for sharing workspaces so that you and your friend can (in essence) cooperatively edit and run the same set of java files in real time.

Something like this - http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2011/07/cloud9s-web-based-real-time-co.php

The answer is No.  Eclipse doesn't support this directly.

However, there is an Eclipse plugin / project called [Saros](http://www.saros-project.org/) that claims to do this.  And the Saros site has links to [related projects](http://www.saros-project.org/#Related_Work) that may be relevant.

(FYI - the relevant search terms are "collaborative programming".)

Comment: great! I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

Answer (score 1):

SVN or CVS - kind of version controlling system will help u to work together or u want to maintain your repository online then kindly check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories link.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SVN Notifier](http://svnnotifier.tigris.org/) which sits in the system tray and notifies me every time the repository changes. And I can highly recommend it. It means you only update when there's something to update!

Alternatively you can set up a scheduled task/cron job to run `svn update` in the appropriate directory every hour/day/whatever.

refer [this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) on setting up a scheduled task.

You want a batch file called svnUpdate.bat or something which looks like this:

```
    cd C:/path/to/your/working/copy

svn update
```

Get the scheduled task to run this as often as you like (once an hour seems sensible)

Make sure you have the command line version of svn installed (I use [SlikSvn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)) and available on your PATH (in a command window type `svn` and ensure it says 'Type svn help...' or similar.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919822/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-subversion-working-copy

Comment: To achieve this there are many ways. the above one one possible way