# What causes SVN “Working copy <path> is locked”?

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn

I wrote a console application that uses SharpSVN to update 3 folders in my repository. Wanted to convert that to a batch script to removed the dependency on SharpSVN.

Came up with this:

```
CD C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC\Core" /closeonend:0
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC\Modules" /closeonend:0
START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:"C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\MW" /closeonend:0
```

I found [this as an answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3943508/1189566). When I run it, I get 3 windows pop up from Tortoise.

One says:

`Error: Working copy 'C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC' locked.

Error: 'C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC' is already locked.`

A second one says:

`Error: Working copy 'C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager' locked.

Error: 'C:\AMG\trunk\AMG_AccountManager\AMC' is already locked.`

And the third one successfully updates the Modules folder. Anyone know what's causing the first two to be locked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't perform three simultaneous update operations on the same working copy. It's by design and that's exactly what working copy locking accomplishes.

If you want to use TortoiseSVN you'll have to use the `/wait` flag of the [`start` command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx) and do updates one by one:

> /wait   : Starts an application and waits for it to end.

If you don't need a fancy GUI you can just call `svn` directly (assuming you selected the command line tools when you installed TortoiseSVN).

Comment: Oh, I see. So do i just do like `START TortoiseProc.exe /wait <everything else in my original post>`?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself. Beware that `/wait` is a flag of `start`, not `TortoiseProc.exe`.

Comment: Thanks. I did START /wait <everything else> and that works, but I have to click "OK" on the screen that Tortoise throws up before it'll update the next one... Not sure if I like this more than my existing Console app which just does them all. Thanks again.

Comment: It's possible that `/closeonend:0` is not getting passed to `TortoiseProc.exe`. Batch syntax is terribly difficult to get right.

Comment: Nah, that was my mistake. It should be a `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: As @ÁlvaroG.Vicario points out, the *most* appropriate way to resolve this is to not use TortoiseProc.exe at all - just run `svn.exe`, and without the `start`. That will ensure that you're A) using the right tool for the job and B) not getting conflicting processes.

Comment: I'll find out, giant corporation so I don't know if they were installed on every machine or not.