# Is there any way to automatically "Update solution to the latest version" from SVN in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, svn

Every time someone checks-in his code I should press "Update solution to the latest version". This would, in most of cases, avoid the need of merging the projects.

Is it possible to automatize this process in some way?

Comment: I'm not sure I would want this feature. What if there was a merge conflict? What if the build was broken?

Comment: Yes, I understand. But they said us to check-in just when we are sure the code is ready to be deployed in production. And it's better to anticipate the merge conflict asap. I think.

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919822/how-do-i-automatically-update-a-subversion-working-copy